# Iteration of text file

Tags: python

I am trying to learn machine learning when I come across this behavior.
From :https://towardsdatascience.com/time-series-classification-using-dynamic-time-warping-61dcd9e143f6, a text file is basically opened (X_train.txt).

```
x_train_file = open(r'UCI HAR Dataset/train/X_train.txt', 'r')
y_train_file = open(r'UCI HAR Dataset/train/y_train.txt', 'r')
x_test_file = open(r'UCI HAR Dataset/test/X_test.txt', 'r')
y_test_file = open(r'UCI HAR Dataset/test/y_test.txt', 'r')
# Create empty lists
x_train = []
y_train = []
x_test = []
y_test = []
# Mapping table for classes
labels = {1:'WALKING', 2:'WALKING UPSTAIRS', 3:'WALKING DOWNSTAIRS',
          4:'SITTING', 5:'STANDING', 6:'LAYING'}
# Loop through datasets
for x in x_train_file:
    x_train.append([float(ts) for ts in x.split()])
```

I opened it normally on notepad first and checked the contents.
It is something like:

```
  2.8858451e-001 -2.0294171e-002 -1.3290514e-001 -9.9527860e-001 -9.8311061e-001 -9.1352645e-001 -9.9511208e-001 -9.8318457e-001.....
```

However, in the tutorial, he was able to open the text file and iterate through the contents as if the contents of the text file is an array or numpy array. How is this possible? I was expecting that the reading the file would be more tedious, like doing some string splitting. Also, I was expecting that iterating (for i in text_file:...) will result in individual chars (In the case above: \n\n2.8858451e-001)

[image]

Edit: I'd like to expand more. I did try to replicate the code. My code is this:
[image]
So I basically just opened the text file. How did global_vars.training get an array like data? Note that I didn't do any string splitting, so I expected to get a single character for each iteration (thus, for each index of global_vars.training)

Comment: `for i in fileobject` returns each _line_ of text.

Comment: Also, I don't understand the question _How is this possible? I was expecting that the reading the file would be more tedious, like doing some string splitting_, because the last line of code in your question does **exactly that**.

Comment: "Also, I was expecting that iterating (for i in text_file:...) will result in individual chars (In the case above: \n\n2.8858451e-001)" - **Did you try to check this**? If you try writing code that only does that loop, and shows you the `i` values that result, does that answer your question? What exactly is confusing here?

Answer (score 1):

The key is this line:

```
x_train.append([float(ts) for ts in x.split()])
```

This is what we call "string parsing". In this case, the author uses `x.split()` to break up each line of text at the spaces. Then they convert the digits into a numerical value with `float(ts)`. Each row of numbers is appended to a list so that they can be used later.

This is one of the powers of python. We can do complex operations with a single line of code. But at the same time, you might not write the code this way to begin with. You can also write this out in multiple lines using a for loop instead of a list comprehension. If it is easier to understand that way, feel free to do so.

Comment: I was confused. It's all good now. I was confused because I checked the file in notepad. On opening it on VS code, I could clearly see the file structure and where the actual '\n' (next lines) are located.

Comment: @user139731 I think the other thing that you may have been confused about that I didn't mention in my answer is that the `for` loop iterates over each line, not each character, from the file.